# how to use SP.UI.Notify or Jquery to show real time messages in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to use SP.UI.Notify in Sharepoint 2010 to display messages when a new document is added or a new item is posted.
So if the users are on the page  i ust want the message to popup.
Is this possible just thinking how can i trigger this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a notification on the page is easy, using SP.UI.Notify.addNotification.
However, knowing when a new document is posted is not so easy.
What you could do, is:

- Create a 'log' custom list with 2 field, Title and a new DateTime field

Then add a webpart or control in the master page that:

- Check from the 'log' list the last time the current user got to the page
- Run a CAML query to get item created or modified after this date
- If there is new item, display a notification
- Update the 'log' list to record the current time for the current user

This can be either done on the server side or on the client side using the JavaScript Object Model.

Comment: Thanks for that Nico.Do you know how i can tell SP.UI.Notify to show a message lets say every 10 minutes?